# install windows 10 after ubuntu

Tags: windows, installation

I have Ubuntu 14.04 in my HDD.

And I will put SSD to my PC and want to install windows 10 on it.

When I searched how to install windows after ubuntu,

there were instructions about partitioning and formatting.

https://silentinfotech.com/blog/steps-to-install-windows-10-on-existing-ubuntu-16-04/

But because I will add new driver so I think I don't need to do it.

And what I need to do is grup install and boot-repair.

Is it correct?

Or should I start from the partitioning though I will add new physical driver?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to create new partition(s) on your new drive.

First, you should create a new partition table (make sure to select gpt type). Then, follow the instructions on your tuto. If you want so details about partition table have a look [here](https://gparted.org/why-partition.php#:%7E:text=As%20a%20general%20rule%2C%20each,contain%20only%20one%20partition%20table.&text=Older%20Windows%20versions%2C%20such%20as,and%20an%20MSDOS%20partition%20table.).